# Why can't I wrap Await in parenthesis in a statement?

Tags: vb.net, async-await

In C#, I have some code that looks like:

```
(await GetBoolAsync()).ShouldBeTrue();
```

`ShouldBeTrue()` is an extension method from the [Shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) library that operates on Booleans.

VB.NET doesn't seem to like wrapping the Await keyword in parenthesis:

```
(Await GetBoolAsync()).ShouldBeTrue()
```

The compiler reports a syntax error on the opening parenthesis at the beginning of the line. I can work around it by declaring an intermediate variable, but is there a way to achieve this in one line like C#?

A full console application to reproduce this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1

    Sub Main
    End Sub

    Async Function Test() As Task
        (Await GetBoolAsync()).ShouldBeTrue()
    End Function

    Function GetBoolAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
        Return Task.FromResult(True)
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub ShouldBeTrue(x As Boolean)
    End Sub

End Module
```

The error is very unhelpful:

> error BC30035: Syntax error.

Comment: That syntax should work - are you sure there isn't something else going on?

Comment: @Mark Ah, my bad. Might help to have an MCVE that actually works. :) fixed to better reflect my actual error.

Comment: Please show previous line as well, take screenshot of the error message and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special syntax for doing so - you should use the `Call` keyword:

```
Async Function Test() As Task
    Call (Await GetBoolAsync()).ShouldBeTrue()
End Function
```

That's because you cannot directly call a member of non-literal expression in Visual Basic, like you would in C#:

```
(5).ToString() 'It is wrong!
```

And in this particular case this includes the result of `Await`.

Hope that helps!