# Does Async in Parentheses Block? (Non-literal Expression)

Tags: c#, async-await

Will the following line...

```
var isAuthorized = (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...)).Succeeded;
```

...result in an asynchronous execution which differs to the caller until the result of `AuthorizeAsync(...)` is found, or will it block the thread until the result is found? Why or why not?

According to [this question for vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33950868/4682228), such an expression is known as non-literal. Based on questions and answers from [Fluently Calling Await without Parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744587/fluently-calling-await-without-parentheses) and [How to Design Fluent Async Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32112418/4682228), this statement seems fine. However, I want to be sure, and know why from the documentation that makes this particular case clear.

Comment: async generally means it does not block a thread.

Comment: @DanielA.White agreed 100%. Just want to make *sure* that this isn't a weird edge case.

Answer (score 9):

Here:

```
var object = _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...)
```

object =  the task itself.

---

Here:

```
var object = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...)
```

object = the evaluation of the task, aka it's result.

---

Here

```
var object = (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...)).Succeeded;
```

you're playing with the evaluation. (It won't block anything, it's not like using `_authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...).Result`).

---

This:

```
var object = (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...)).Succeeded
```

is this, but in a single line

```
var aux = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(...);
var object = aux.Succeeded;
```